# Shall I bundle all my react js files

Tags: reactjs, gulp, bundle, browserify

I'm new to react and gulp. And I have a question that night look silly to experts but I've been struggling with it for quite sometime

I'm building a react project with a few react files and I try to bundle then with browserify and gulp but it seems browserify only receives one entry. Considering that I have imported all the necessary files to App.js, will those files be bundled as well?

Comment: Have you tried [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)?

Answer (score 1):

In simple words, entry point is the point where your compiler starts compiling. From thereon, it checks all of your file imports and keeps adding it to the bundle file.

So yes, all the imported and used modules will be compiled in your application.

Also, if you're new, I suggest you try the `create-react-app`. Once you're experienced with how things work, you can delve deeper into `create-react-app` by ejecting it (which is not recommended ;))

Answer (score 0):

If you decide not to use `create-react-app`, you can look into [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [parcel](https://parceljs.org/) to replace `gulp`.